# Drop all databases that start with a specific string on Mongo shell

Tags: mongodb, shell, mongo-shell

I have a huge list of mongodb databases and I want to remove all databases that start with the string "2019" using mongo shell command

I found the command to list them

```
db.adminCommand( { listDatabases: 1, filter: { "name": /^2019/ } } )
```

I just want to drop the output of that command.

Comment: why you dont write a javascript loop and dropDatabase() in each in of those?

Comment: @Takis I want to do it from mongo shell. Preferably with a single command.

Comment: mongo shell can run javascript code, or load javascript from files

Comment: @Takis So There is no easier way to bulk delete databases with a filter?

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/dropDatabase/#mongodb-dbcommand-dbcmd.dropDatabase the command doesnt allow any filter, but i dont know what is the problem, even if you have thousands of databases to delete, the loop will be fast. maybe someone else can help more

Answer (score 0):

Pasting this into `mongosh` drops every database whose name begins with YOUR-PREFIX-HERE:

```
(() => {
  db.adminCommand(
    { 
      listDatabases: 1,
      filter: { "name": /^YOUR-PREFIX-HERE/ } 
    }
  )
    .databases.map(({ name }) => name)
    .forEach(name => {
      const db2 = db.getSiblingDB(name);
      db2.dropDatabase();
    });
})();
```

The key thing is to use `db.getSiblingDB` to get a reference to each database. `dropDatabase()` doesn't take a name, you have to call it on a database object referring to the correct database.